# Why does this bat not work

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, tasks, start

```
@echo off
start ButtonFix.exe
cd "D:\KASE-EO\FruitMachine\LED\LEDBlinky"
start AttractActivate.exe
cd "D:\FME FX3\JoyToKey\bin"
start JoyToKey.exe"
cd "D:\FME FX3"
start/wait FruitMachineEmulation.exe

Taskkill / f /im "ButtonFix.exe"
Taskkill / f /im "AttractActivate.exe" 
exit
```

I created the above file so after closing `FruitMachineEmulation.exe` it would then Taskkill `ButtonFix.exe` and `attactacviate.exe` but it did not work can anyone see why many thanks rob
(I am still learning here so please help)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
Taskkill /f /im "ButtonFix.exe"
Taskkill /f /im "AttractActivate.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

because there is a space between / and f

```
Taskkill / f /im "ButtonFix.exe"
Taskkill / f /im "AttractActivate.exe"
```

they should be:

```
Taskkill /f /im "ButtonFix.exe"
Taskkill /f /im "AttractActivate.exe"
```